# EF Core 7.0.3 Throws Null Reference Exception when trying to build JSON column

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working off of the samples provided by Microsoft [here][1] but trimmed down

```
public class Address{
    public Address(string street, string city){
        Street = street;
        City = city;
    }
    public string Street{get;set;}
    public string City{get;set;}
}

public class ContactDetails{
    public Address Address{get;set;}=null!;
    public string? Phone{get;set;}
}

public class Author{
    public Author(string name){
        Name = name;
    }
    public int Id{get;private set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public ContactDetails Contact{get;set;}=null!;
}

public UserDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserDbContext> options) : base(options){
    Database.EnsureCreated();
}
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
        modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().OwnsOne(
            author=>author.Contact, ownedNavigationBuilder=>{
                ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
                ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsOne(contactDetails=>contactDetails.Address);
        });
    }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors =>Set<Author>();
}
```

Whenever I try create a `UserDbContext` I get a Null Reference Exception  when trying to execute `OnModelCreating`

If I change to

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().OwnsOne(
    author=>author.Contact, ownedNavigationBuilder=>{
        ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsOne(contactDetails=>contactDetails.Address);
    });
```

it works fine as you can imagine adding columns for all the `ContactDetails` fields, so this rules out any other issues with my code I believe
[1]: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7-release-candidate-2/

Comment: Hi @MDK, how do you inject the `Database` when you call the `Database.EnsureCreated();`? Also how do you create the DbContext and get the null reference exception? I just use the ef core default way to add migration and update database, then inject the DbContext to read the Author table value, everything works fine.

Comment: @Rena I was following the model laid out in the ASP.Net Core documentation.  I went as far as to even download samples from the Git Repo.  Turns out that SQLite is not supported for JSON Columns YET.  I found this out when I created an issue on the source repo